# How to capture the URL change with popstate?

Tags: javascript, popstate

I would like to capture the URL change on a local site such as if:

http://myexample.com/

Is changed on:

http://myexample.com/foobar

I can intercept the change and load `foobar` with AJAX.

So I wrote this:

```
window.onpopstate = function (event) {
  console.log(event)
  history.pushState(42, '', "#baseState");
}
```

I get the event when I test with:

```
http://myexample.com/#hello-world
```

But if I do:

```
http://myexample.com/foobar
```

My browser still make a request to the server to load foobar, and of course I get a 404 error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: So this URL change is triggered by what - just a normal link click? Then popstate is the wrong event to be looking at in the first place, it doesn’t fire for that. Just add a click handler to your links that prevents the default action, and performs your AJAX request instead …?

Comment: Everything. A change on the Location bar, a link being clicked or the previous, next event in the browser.

Comment: have you considered usi9ng a library that manipulates history API for that that is cross-browser for example?